# Request connecting with multiple entrance to UK

Tags: visas, uk, multiple-entry

I have UK C-Visit MULT Visa for 180 days. May I enter to UK twice during that period? My first visit was about one month ago and now I want to go for a holiday?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. MULT means multiple entry. You can go as many times as you wish, but must leave the UK on or before the expiry date of the visa (and obtain a new visa if you wish to return after that date).